# How to make Spring Boot to connect to SSL&Certificate Mysql Connection

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have a remote Mysql server running with SSL + Certificate security. I can make a standalone Java JDBC connection work properly using my self-made keystore and truststore.jks . The problem is that I can't find any documentation or website that teaches how to plug into springboot a mysql database that uses SSL + Certificates protection. My application.properties file has this:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{remote-ip}:3306/{database-name}?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

And inside Eclipse, i have under the JVM-arguments field, this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="{path}\truststore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="xxxxx" -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
-Djavax..net.ssl.keyStore="{path}\keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="xxxxx"
```

It won't work. Gives me this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '{database-user}'@'{remote-ip}' (using password: YES)
```